# How to count the collection of subsets of a finite set where each element belongs to at least one subset of the collection?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

As an example, consider the set $X=\{1,2,3\}$ then all its possible subsets $X^*=P(X)$ (eight of them, of course) finally the I want to count the collections of these subsets (elements of $P(X^*)$ that have the property that every element belongs to at least one set.

If the cardinality of $X$ is 2, I know the answer is five: $a:\{\{1,2\}\}, b:\{\{1\},\{2\}\},c:\{\{1,2\},\{1\}\}, d:\{\{1,2\},\{2\}\}, e:\{\{1,2\},\{1\},\{2\}\}$. But is there a systematic way to count this collections of subsets when $X$ has a higher cardinality?

Comment: I wanted to brute-force but it would be $O(2^{2^n})$... sad life

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003465 ... I cannot think of a systematic way to count these ... but there maybe a ref in the link ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit $a(n) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \dbinom n k 2^{2^{n-k}~~-1}$ from your link

Comment: In https://oeis.org/A003465 the following formula is given (by Michael Somos) 
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_n= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} 2^{2^{n-k}} 
\end{eqnarray*}
This can probably be shown using an inclusion-exclusion arguement ( and allow the empty set to be included.)
@KennyLau ... you are 3 minutes ahead of me !